# Overriding angularJS directive functioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular-pageslide directive in my project.
I am facing a problem that when I click anywhere on the body of the pageslide, when the slider is open, a class that I have added to HTML changes to 'close' one instead of staying 'open' one.
(Basically onClick changes ng-pageslide-body-open to ng-pageslide-body-closed).
This is happening because the angular pageslide directive calls a function to setClass, using onClick.

```
if (param.keyListener) {

                            $document.off('keydown', handleKeyDown);

                        }

 

                        if (param.clickOutside) {

                            $document.off('touchend click', onBodyClick);

                        }

                        isOpen = false;

                        setBodyClass('closed');

                        scope.psOpen = false;


  function setBodyClass(value){

                        if (param.bodyClass) {

                            var bodyClass = param.className + '-body';

                            var bodyClassRe = new RegExp(bodyClass + '-closed|' + bodyClass + '-open');

                            body.className = body.className.replace(bodyClassRe, '');

                            var newBodyClassName = bodyClass + '-' + value;

                            if (body.className[body.className.length -1] !== ' ') {

                                body.className += ' ' + newBodyClassName;

                            } else {

                                body.className += newBodyClassName;

                            }

                        }

                    }
```

However, I need to stop that from happening using my own controller. Is there any way through which I can achieve that?
**I tried using the Timeout function, which works but because it requires a millisecond parameter, it doesn't look correct.**
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you used this https://github.com/danielepiccone/ng-pageslide the same way as in the examples, or started writing your own implementation?

Comment: Did it in the same way as examples.